# Correlate subsets of data in R

Tags: r, correlation

I  have data like so:

```
DepVar = c(2,3,5,6,1,3)
Var1 = c(1,7,2,1,1,2)
Var2 = c(0,8,3,3,4,6)    
Group = c("a", "c", "c","b","a","a") 
df = data.frame(Group, DepVar, Var1, Var2)
```

I would like to correlate Var1 & Var2 against the DepVar column, for all observations within a group. So my output would be structured like this (correlations are made up):

```
Group | Var1 | Var2
  a   |  0.6 |  0.2
  b   |  0.3 |  0.1
  c   |  0.4 |  0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` to group the data by `Group` and summarize the dataset by `cor`. Because in your example dataset `b` only has one observation, the correlation coefficient is `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Var1 = cor(DepVar, Var1),
            Var2 = cor(DepVar, Var2)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
df2
#   Group       Var1       Var2
# 1     a  0.8660254  0.3273268
# 2     b         NA         NA
# 3     c -1.0000000 -1.0000000
```

If you have many columns to conduct the same correlation based on `DepVar`, we can use `summarise_at` instead of `summarise`.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-DepVar), funs(cor(DepVar, .))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
df2
#   Group       Var1       Var2
# 1     a  0.8660254  0.3273268
# 2     b         NA         NA
# 3     c -1.0000000 -1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to easily add in a column for the count of observations for each group? So it would go c(3,1,2)

Comment: @NBC Try change the `summarise` call to this:  `summarise(Var1 = cor(DepVar, Var1),
            Var2 = cor(DepVar, Var2),
            Count = n())`

Comment: that crashes my r GUI? not sure why